# Tissue addon frame fill mode cant be tessellated (error)

Tags: add-on, error

I recently discovered tissue addon and started to experiment with it. Everything works great, only frame fill mode is allways making error no matter what the shape of segment I try (I tried even exactly same segment as is mentioned in Bblender manual and I checked normals). What am I doing wrong? - I just want to make same tessellation as is in the manual.
Can someone show how to make this example? Thank you so much, I am getting numb from trying over and over.
(Also patch is making same tessellation as quad, but I can make another thread about it)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All solved - the built-in tissue addon is damaged - you need to erase its source codes and replace it with a stable version which you have to download separately.

This version works: https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue/releases/tag/v0-3-54

Now everything works.